# Can't do form1 code if form2 is running

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a program that has two forms. Form1 is always running, form2 can be opened. If form2 is opened then form1's code doesn't execute, but if I do form2.show the form2 becomes unresponsive. So I was trying different code and I was able to open form2 without crashing. with this line of code.

```
Application.Run(Form2)
```

I need to be able to have form2 running and have form2's code execute and also have form1's code execute. When I open form2 it'll be running form2's code but form1's code will be put on hold until form2 is closed. Is their a way I can have both form's running their code?

Answer (score 0):

Try having the program start a main() function.  So change the properties to have the main function be the start function.

From there you can instantiate and open each one of the 2 forms and they should run independently.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Main()

Comment: On You Project Properties in the Application Tab.  It used to be you could select any function or sub as the startup.

Comment: Now, you are going to have to declare a NewForm if you have a Windows Form Application.  From this "third" form, instantiate the 2 forms isn the following and call their "show" method from the third form.  You can also hide this 3rd form.

Comment: The form2 is showing up perfectly fine, it's just when the form2 is open form1 code it put on pause or hold until form2 closes.

Comment: where are you declaring form2? In the code for form1?

Comment: I think your issue is that you are starting a "Second application with Form2" by doing "Application.Run(Form2)"   -- You should try declaring the form2 instead by doing something like                                   Dim f as New Form2                                                        then you can open the form by using: f.show().

Comment: Tried it and the form doesn't even show up if I do f.show()